# strange colors/textures on render - looks fine in viewport

Tags: cycles-render-engine

So I am not sure if I did something wrong here but, I am creating a sort of demonic creature and it looks like this in the layout window in Render view (Cycles):

[image]

and in Texture preview mode it looks like this (closer up shot)

[image]

However, in the Render tab, and when I go to actually render the image, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Please share a screenshot of your settings for a quicker answer. Also, did you add lights to your scene?

Comment: maybe your lights are not visible in render, you need to check that in the Outliner